# React Native: "Rendered fewer hooks than expected." No clue what this means, app crashes?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jsx

I have an AuthScreen that should handle all the login, register, forgotPassword etc. logic. Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { RootStateOrAny, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { authForgotPassword, authLogin, authRegister } from '../store/actions/authActions';

import ForgotPassword from '../components/Auth/ForgotPassword';
import Login from '../components/Auth/Login';
import PageType from '../utils/PageType';
import Register from '../components/Auth/Register';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';

type ParamList = {
    AuthLoadingScreen: undefined;
    HomeTabScreen: undefined;
    AuthScreen: undefined
}

type AuthScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<ParamList, 'AuthScreen'>;

type Props = {
    navigation: AuthScreenNavigationProp;
}

export default function AuthScreen({ navigation }: Props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const user = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.auth.user);
    
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [password2, setPassword2] = useState('');

    const [showPage, setShowPage] = useState(PageType.Login);

    const changePage = (pageType: PageType) => {
        setEmail('');
        setPassword('');
        setPassword2('');
        setShowPage(pageType);
    }

    const login = () => {
        dispatch(authLogin(email, password));
    }

    const register = () => {
        if (password === password2) {
            dispatch(authRegister(email, password));
        } else {
            alert('Passwords must match!');
        }
    }

    const forgotPassword = () => {
        dispatch(authForgotPassword(email, changePage));
    }

    if (user) {
        navigation.navigate('HomeTabScreen');
        return null;
    } else {
        switch(showPage) {
            case PageType.Login: {
                return Login(email, setEmail, password, setPassword, changePage, login);
            }
            case PageType.Register: {
                return Register(email, setEmail, password, setPassword, password2, setPassword2, changePage, register);
            }
            case PageType.ForgotPassword: {
                return ForgotPassword(email, setEmail, changePage, forgotPassword);
            }
            default: return Login(email, setEmail, password, setPassword, changePage, login);
        }
    }
}
```

I have components "Login", "Register" and "ForgotPassword" each displaying (returning) different layout, actions etc.

So I've made a hook and a switch case, when pressing "register here" for example in the "Login" component, it will call "changePage" with the REGISTER page value. It should re-render "AuthScreen", see that "showPage" value is changed to "REGISTER" and then go into my switch-case again, and return the "REGISTER" value. That's my idea behind it anyways.

The error occurs trying to set the showPage hook "setShowPage(pageType);" in "changePage" function. If I comment this, the app doesn't crash, but neither does it change pages.

What does this mean and how can I fix my Screen?

Comment: I think its with the way you are returning components from the switch statement.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, have you considered using react-router?

Comment: @im_baby no, can you use it with react-native as well? Also I've tried looking into Nested Navigators, to create a Switch Navigator for my Loading page, Auth page, Home page etc. and then another one for my Auth pages itself (Login, Register, ForgotPassword) but then when trying to navigate to Home page, it says no page under that navigator exists :s

Comment: React-router can be used in native https://reactrouter.com/native. But as another user suggests react-navigation may be a good fit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would recommend to use [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) for this, the issue seems to be with the way you are returning the components and passing props to them, for example `Login(email, setEmail, password, setPassword, changePage, login)` should be `<Login email={email} setEmail={setEmail} password={password} setPassword={setPassword} changePage={changePage} login={login}/>`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { RootStateOrAny, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { authForgotPassword, authLogin, authRegister } from '../store/actions/authActions';

import ForgotPassword from '../components/Auth/ForgotPassword';
import Login from '../components/Auth/Login';
import PageType from '../utils/PageType';
import Register from '../components/Auth/Register';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';

type ParamList = {
    AuthLoadingScreen: undefined;
    HomeTabScreen: undefined;
    AuthScreen: undefined
}

type AuthScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<ParamList, 'AuthScreen'>;

type Props = {
    navigation: AuthScreenNavigationProp;
}

export default function AuthScreen({ navigation }: Props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const user = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.auth.user);
    
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [password2, setPassword2] = useState('');

    const [showPage, setShowPage] = useState(PageType.Login);

    const changePage = (pageType: PageType) => {
        setEmail('');
        setPassword('');
        setPassword2('');
        setShowPage(pageType);
    }

    const login = () => {
        dispatch(authLogin(email, password));
    }

    const register = () => {
        if (password === password2) {
            dispatch(authRegister(email, password));
        } else {
            alert('Passwords must match!');
        }
    }

    const forgotPassword = () => {
        dispatch(authForgotPassword(email, changePage));
    }

    if (user) {
        navigation.navigate('HomeTabScreen');
        return null;
    } else {
        switch(showPage) {
            case PageType.Login: {
                return <Login email={email} setEmail={setEmail} password={password} setPassword={setPassword} changePage={changePage} login={login}/>
            }
            case PageType.Register: {
                return <Register email={email} setEmail={setEmail} password={password} setPassword={setPassword} password2={password2} setPassword2={setPassword2} changePage={changePage} register={register}/>
            }
            case PageType.ForgotPassword: {
                return <ForgotPassword email={email} setEmail={setEmail} changePage={changePage} forgotPassword={forgotPassword}/>
            }
            default: return <Login email={email} setEmail={setEmail} password={password} setPassword={setPassword} changePage={changePage} login={login}/>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would YOU do it if you had to do this logic? With react-navigation?

Comment: You should ask another question for that if this answer solves it for you, I can answer that as well.

Comment: Also navigation on react native is a bit more complicated as it is different for Tabs and Drawers.

Comment: But ofcourse! I was staring at it blindly but how I could've overlooked something this simple... I'll ask another question and tag you in it if I can :)

Comment: I've made a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268327/react-native-how-to-properly-handle-nested-navigation

Comment: @Tempuslight ok will check it out in a bit

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, Login / Register / ForgotPassword are functional components. Those should be returned like

```
return <Login email={email} setEmail={setEmail} ... />
```

and not just a plain function calls like you do now:

```
return Login(email, setEmail)
```

If you are not using jsx/tsx, then you should call it like this:

```
React.createElement(Login, { email, setEmail, ... }, ...children)
```

But generally, instead of this component, why don't you just use React Router and add a separate `<Route />` for Login, Register, ForgotPassword, etc...? That would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: But ofcourse...?!! Sigh I was staring myself blind at this, how could I have overlooked lol?

Comment: Happens to the best of us. :)