# React Native: how to properly handle nested navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So what I have for my app is as follows:

1. AuthLoading screen => will handle a check if user is already logged in, if so redirect to HomeTabScreen, if not redirect to AuthScreen/Login
2. AuthScreen/Login => should handle the Login, Register and ForgotPassword components
3. HomeTabScreen => the main entry point into the rest of my app (a BottomTabNavigator)

These 3 screens/components are made so, in a SwitchNavigator:

```
const HomeTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeTabScreen() {
  return(
    <HomeTab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
          let iconName;

          if (route.name == 'Home') {
            iconName = 'ios-home-outline'
          } else if (route.name == 'Discover') {
            iconName = 'globe-outline'
          } else if (route.name == 'Profile') {
            iconName = 'person-outline'
          }

          return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
        }
      })}
      tabBarOptions={{ 
        activeTintColor: '#FFCD1B',
        inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
        labelStyle: { textTransform: 'none', fontSize: 16 },
        style: {
          borderTopColor: '#2D2E2D',
          height: 60,
        },
        tabStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#2D2E2D',
          paddingVertical: 5,
        }
      }}
      initialRouteName='Home'
    >
      <HomeTab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
      <HomeTab.Screen name="Discover" component={DiscoverScreen} />
      <HomeTab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    </HomeTab.Navigator>
  )
}

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return(
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  )
}

const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoadingScreen,
    AuthScreen,
    HomeTabScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoadingScreen'
  }
)
```

So here's the scenario that I would want:

A user opens the app, enters "AuthLoading". App checks user is noth authenticated yet, so redirects to Authscreen/Login. Right now "AuthScreen" handles 3 separate components based on a hook that I set, an enum that chooses which "subcomponent" of "AuthScreen" to load, like so:

```
switch(showPage) {
            case PageType.Login: {
                return <Login email={email} setEmail={setEmail} password={password} setPassword={setPassword} changePage={changePage} register={register}></Login>;
            }
            case PageType.Register: {
                return <Register email={email} setEmail={setEmail} password={password} setPassword={setPassword}
                    password2={password2} setPassword2={setPassword2} changePage={changePage} register={register}></Register>;
            }
            case PageType.ForgotPassword: {
                return <ForgotPassword email={email} setEmail={setEmail} changePage={changePage} forgotPassword={forgotPassword}></ForgotPassword>;
            }
            default: return <Login email={email} setEmail={setEmail} password={password} setPassword={setPassword} changePage={changePage} register={register}></Login>;
        }
```

This to me, looks kind of horrible. However when I tried replacing my "AuthScreen" in my SwitchNavigator with another Stack/Switch navigator, it would create issues when trying to navigate to "HomeTabScreen" as it would say no navigator has that name value and it can't navigate.

Is there a way to cleanly do this, preferably in my app using all those navigators in one place? So that for example I'll have an "AuthLoadingScreen", "AuthSwitchNavigator" and "HomeTabScreen" (tab navigator) and that I can navigate from my "AuthSwitchNavigator" to my "HomeTabScreen" without it saying it doesn't exist. I also won't add "HomeTabScreen" as another StackScreen or whatever, because the Android "back" button will just go "back" in the stack, displaying Login etc again (when user is logged in, I obviously do not want this).

TL;DR: How to properly handle nested navigation with multiple switch, stack and tab navigators all in one clean way?

Comment: @yudhiesh Here's my new question :)

Comment: Instead of conditionally rendering based on the `switchPage` param what you can do is use the [initialRouteName](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#initialroutename) prop of the `Stack.Navigator` component. You can store the value of your route that you want to be the initial one inside of your global state.  All you have to do then is to stack screens inside of one navigator and set its `initialRouteName` prop to the one from your global state.